# web2py FORM - lookup value by string field instead of ID

Tags: python, web2py, web2py-modules

I have a model like this in web2py:

```
db.define_table('courses',
    Field('course_name','string'))


db.define_table('auth_user',
    ....
    ....
    Field('course_name',db.courses,label=T('Course Name'),
        required=True,
        requires=IS_IN_DB(db,db.courses.id,'%(course_name)s'),
```

If I display a form based on the auth_user table, the `auth_user.course_name` field is represented by a dropdown menu containing all of the courses in `courses` table. As expected, it displays them using the contents of the `courses.course_name` field, and not the `courses.ID` field (because of the string format representation in the IS_IN_DB requirement.

However, I'm trying to modify it such that instead of using a dropdown select menu, it just displays a text field. I'm expecting the user to be able to enter the name of a course, and the form will work properly as long as that name is a valid `course_name`.

To do that, I added a `widget=SQLFORM.widgets.string.widget` property to the `auth_user.course_name` field. That correctly displays a text box instead of the dropdown, but doesn't allow the user to enter a `course_name`. It works fine if a valid `courses.id` is entered (and displays the expected error message if it's not a valid ID).

However, I can't figure out how to make it accept a `course_name` instead of the ID. I could theoretically use the autocomplete plugin (which does indeed work), but the purpose of this is to allow the user to only submit the form if they know the valid `course_name` (it's kind of like a password).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out by using a custom validation class (replacing the IS_IN_DB validator). For reference, this is what my validator looks like:

```
class COURSE_NAME_VALIDATOR:
    def __init__(self, error_message='Unknown course name. Please see your instructor.'):
        self.e = error_message

    def __call__(self, value):
        if db(db.courses.course_name == value).select():
            return (db(db.courses.course_name == value).select()[0].id, None)
        return (value, self.e)
```

I got the template for the validation class from the web2py manual (http://www.web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#Custom-validators)